# #define scope (microchip studio)

Tags: c-preprocessor, microchip

Im using microchip studio
How can I define F_CPU in main.c file and make all files "see" this definition?

I declared in main.c:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "UART.h"
#define F_CPU 12000000
```

and in UART.c I tried using this definition :

```
        ubrr_value = (F_CPU/(2*BAUD_RATE))-1;
```

i recieved this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
```

Error       'F_CPU' undeclared (first use in this function) UART_TEST   XX\UART_TEST\UART_TEST\UART.c   55

Comment: Does uart.c include uart.h?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define F_CPU in main.c file and make all files "see" this definition?

You can't.

You can define `F_CPU` in your compiler command line arguments. For example gcc compiler takes `-DF_CPU=12000000`. And compile all your sources with that definition.

You can refactor your code, and put `F_CPU` into separate file and include it from all files that need it.

```
// config.h
#deifne F_CPU 12000000

// main.c
#include "config.h"

// uart.c
#include "config.h"
...
        ubrr_value = (F_CPU/(2*BAUD_RATE))-1;
...
```